# Prove that the sum of a set's inverse is positive?

Tags: inequality

I have a set $x_i$ with length $n$, where $n>1$. The set is composed of real positive numbers, $x_i \in \mathbb{R}_{+}$. The mean of the set is equal to 1.

$$
\bar{x_i}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i=1
$$

I want to prove that the summation of the inverse of this set, minus one, is positive. Basically, proving the following:

$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(\frac{1}{x_i}-1\right)\geq0
$$

My main problem is that I'm not sure how to simplify the sum of an inverse of a set. Really appreciate any help on this. Not a math expert, so let me know if there is something obvious I am missing.

Comment: Suppose $n=1$ and $x_1=1$.  Note that you refer to the "mean" of the set but then you write out the sum, not the mean.  Did you mean to say that the sum was $n$?  Or did you mean "sum" when you wrote "mean"?

Comment: If you really meant the sum, and if $n>1$ then each $x_i<1$, clearly, so each term in your second sum is positive.  But it isn't clear what you really meant to ask.

Comment: I corrected the formula to obtain the mean. I forgot to divide the sum by $n$ so that it is the mean.

Comment: Still need to require that $n>1$ though.

Comment: Ok, just edited it to specify that $n>1$. Also, I edited the summation so that it is greater or equal to 0, because, as @lulu says, if the set is composed of a series of 1,1,1..., then it the summation would be 0. But, if there is any variance in the set, it would be positive.

Comment: Your desired inequality follows from the HM-AM Inequality, see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HM-GM-AM-QM_inequalities)  And, yes, you were correct to modify it to $≥0$.

Comment: [Cauchy-Schwarz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality) gives $\left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^n1\right)^2\le\sum\limits_{k=1}^nx_k\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\frac1{x_k}$

Comment: This can be cast a convex minimization problem where we want to show that the minimum is nonnegative.

Answer (score 2):

Original statement:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(\frac{1}{x_i}-1\right)\geq0
$$
Expand the $-1$ as $-n$:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(\frac{1}{x_i}\right)-n\geq0
$$
Add $n$:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(\frac{1}{x_i}\right)\geq n
$$
Divide by $1/n$:
$$
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(\frac{1}{x_i}\right)\geq1
$$
Invert the equation:
$$
\frac{n}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(\frac{1}{x_i}\right)}\leq1
$$

The HM-AM inequalities tell us that $n$ divided by the sum of the set's inverse is smaller or equal to the mean, which is equal to 1:

$$
\frac{n}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(\frac{1}{x_i}\right)}\leq\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(x_i\right)=1
$$

Therefore, the inequality holds:

$$
\frac{n}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(\frac{1}{x_i}\right)}\leq1
$$